# synonym for "worth finding"

Tags: grammar, expressions, synonyms

Can the sentence "It's worth finding a part-time job during the holidays" be replaced by "It's good to find a part-time job during the holidays." Do they mean the same ?

Comment: In that particular context they mean about the same.

Comment: @HotLicks I don't think we actually have enough context to say that.  Depending on the larger context, they *may* be "about the same" or significantly different.  Insufficient data.  Certainly I would not assume they are the same without more information.

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same.  Whether you could substitute "good" for "worth" would depend very much on the context.

"It's good to X" is very generic.  It says there is a benefit but has no meaning of urgency or necessity or superlative benefit or the perils of *not* doing X.  In contrast, "worth" can imply any and all of those extra things.

To me, the use of "worth" implies

> In this specific context, there is a particular benefit to (you) doing X

and may also imply either

> The benefit is so good that not doing X is a missed opportunity

or

> Not doing X will even risk loss/harm.

I am not claiming that everybody would use it that way in every situation, but it often has that implication, which "It's good" does not.  So substituting "good" for "worth" would remove important meaning.

If I were talking to a student facing financial problems, I would say

> It's worth finding a part-time job during the holidays

to emphasise the benefit and the risk of not following the advice.  On the other hand, if I were a student who had luckily found a nice job during the holidays, I might simply say to fellow students

> It's good to find a part-time job during the holidays.

because it was lucky for me but I'm not explicitly trying to tell them to do the same.  In those two situations, choosing the other wording would change the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

They *can* mean the same thing, but "worth it" usually implies that you'll be getting something more than you would ordinarily expect. For instance:

*"It's good to find a part-time job during the holidays."*

"Yeah, you always need a little extra income then."

*"It's worth finding a part-time job during the holidays"*

"Well sure; you can grab the best stuff as it goes on sale, you can choose gifts while you're at work, people are usually much more generous with tips this time of year, there are usually free cookies in the break-room, there's always overtime if you wan't it... (etc.)"